# I'm trying to understand this piece of Scheme code, can someone explain it to me?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

I found this Scheme code on the internet, it outputs all subsets given a list, can someone explain how it works?

```lisp
(define (subsets s) (if (null? s) 
  (list ()) 
    (let ((rest (subsets (cdr s))))(append rest (map (lambda (x) (cons (car s) x)) rest)))))

(subsets '(a b c))
```

Answer (score 2):

You really need to format it:

```
(define (subsets s)
  (if (null? s)
      (list ())
      (let ((rest (subsets (cdr s))))
        (append rest
                (map (lambda (x)
                       (cons (car s) x))
                     rest)))))
```

What it does is return `(())` for the argument `'()`

For a one element argument eg. `'(b)` if binds `rest` to the subsets of every element execept the first.. Which is no elements so `rest` is `(())` and then it returns a list consisting of all the elements in `rest` as well as each list element of `rest` with `b` added to front. Thus `(() (b))`.

For a two element argument eg. `'(a b)` it binds `rest` to the subsets of every element except the first. Which is `(b)` so we know from above that it is `(() (b))` and we know it will use those as well as every element with `a` added to the beginning: `(() (b) (a) (a b))`

I could go on but I'm guessing you get the picture?

Comment: Yes I do thanks for that, however there is one part that still puzzles me.

(append rest (map (lambda (x)(cons (car s) x)) rest))

The more I look at this the more it really seems I should be seeing duplicate characters, but I don't. Could you explain this part in a bit more detail?

Comment: @FierElMomo If `rest` contains `(() (b))` then the first two elements would be that and the last two will be processed by map and get added an element in front of each. Eg. `(() (b) (a) (a b))` from my example does not have duplicates. Only way to get duplucates is if the argument `s` had duplicates. You clearly don't know Scheme so you should perhaps find the same code in a language you know.

Comment: @FierElMomo There are two functions here, you need to understand what each does. The function append takes two lists and concatenates them. Now in (append rest (map (lambda (x) (cons (car s) x) rest)), the first argument to the append function is 'rest' itself. The second argument to append is a list, which in turn, is the output of the map function, which applies the lambda to 'rest' to create a new list, which will be concat'd with the original 'rest' by append. You have to break it down bit by bit to see what's happening

Comment: Yes I'm very new to Scheme, but you helped a lot. I know exactly how it works now thank you.